# I need to find and replace

Tags: vba, ms-word

Find replace in story as well as in footnote or endnote stories Highlight the replacement text too.

```
Sub MultiReplace()
Dim StrOld As String, StrNew As String
Dim RngFind As Range, RngTxt As Range, i As Long
StrOld = "<et al>,<pp>.^32,<p>.^32"
StrNew = "et^sal,pp.^s,p.^s"
Set RngTxt = Selection.Range
For i = 0 To UBound(Split(StrOld, ","))
  Set RngFind = RngTxt.Duplicate
  With RngFind.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = Split(StrOld, ",")(i)
    .Replacement.Text = Split(StrNew, ",")(i)
    .Format = False
    .MatchWholeWord = True
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the *specific* problem you're having with your posted code?

Comment: I need to find in mainstory as well as footnote or endnote sections

Comment: Have you reviewed this ?   https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/using_a_macro_to_replace_text_wherever_it_appears_in_a_document.html

Comment: I suspect that this may be an earlier version of Greg's page: https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/Customization/ReplaceAnywhere.htm

Comment: I am not a that good in coding can anybody help on this please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
Sub MultiReplace()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim RngStory As Range, i As Long
Dim StrOld As String, StrNew As String
StrOld = "<et al>,<pp>.^32,<p>.^32"
StrNew = "et^sal,pp.^s,p.^s"
For Each RngStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
  With RngStory
    Select Case .StoryType
      Case wdMainTextStory, wdEndnotesStory, wdFootnotesStory
        With .Find
          .ClearFormatting
          .Replacement.ClearFormatting
          .MatchWildcards = True
          .Forward = True
          .Wrap = wdFindStop
          .Format = False
           For i = 0 To UBound(Split(StrOld, ","))
            .Text = Split(StrOld, ",")(i)
            .Replacement.Text = Split(StrNew, ",")(i)
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
           Next
        End With
    End Select
  End With
Next RngStory
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```